# How do you manage an explosion of update paths/Msg constructors?

Tags: elm

I've finished the Elm guide and noticed on [very simple examples](https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/checkboxes.html), the `update` function grows to 3 cases and the `Msg` type can have 3 constructors.  I imagine on an intermediate project, this would grow to 20 and on an advance project, it might be hundreds.  How do you manage this?  I foresee this being a source of version control contention if every developer needs to add a new constructor for their feature.

I worked on a react-redux project and it has a concept of [combining reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to solve this problem.  I did not run across that concept in Elm.  Does it have one?

Comment: Found a good answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/5jd2xn/how_to_structure_elm_with_multiple_models/dbuu0m4/

Comment: When the Elm Europe videos are posted I suggest you watch Richard Feldman's preso

Answer (score 6):

You can define msg type consists of child/sub msg types, and of course, updater can be combined with sub functions.  ie.

```
-- Counter


type CounterMsg
    = Increment
    | Decrement


type alias CounterModel =
    Int


updateCounter : CounterMsg -> CounterModel -> ( CounterModel, Cmd msg )
updateCounter msg model =
    case msg of
        Increment ->
            ( model + 1, Cmd.none )

        Decrement ->
            ( model - 1, Cmd.none )



-- Todo


type TodoMsg
    = AddTodo String


type alias TodoModel =
    List String


updateTodo : TodoMsg -> TodoModel -> ( TodoModel, Cmd msg )
updateTodo msg model =
    case msg of
        AddTodo str ->
            ( str :: model, Cmd.none )



-- unified


type alias Model =
    { counter : CounterModel
    , todos : TodoModel
    }


type Msg
    = Counter CounterMsg
    | Todo TodoMsg


initModel =
    { counter = 0, todos = [] }


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd msg )
update msg model =
    case Debug.log "message" msg of
        Counter countermsg ->
            let
                ( newmodel, cmd ) =
                    updateCounter countermsg model.counter
            in
                ( { model | counter = newmodel }, cmd )

        -- etc...
        _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Richard's implementation for RealWorld/Conduit](https://dev.to/rtfeldman/tour-of-an-open-source-elm-spa). It provides a realistic way to structure a large enough app (few thousands lines of code).

In short, on complex projects there is the idea of a Page that can have its own model and update and view.

Within each page you could have a large Msg but that is not really an issue. 20 tags is actually quite manageable. 50 is also manageable as discovered by NoRedInk programmers in their production code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent tutorial on the topic here:  https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en-v01/02-elm-arch/07-composing-2.html

I wish it showed the source of the Widget, but I can imagine what it looks like.  Inlining for posterity.

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, program)
import Widget


-- MODEL


type alias AppModel =
    { widgetModel : Widget.Model
    }


initialModel : AppModel
initialModel =
    { widgetModel = Widget.initialModel
    }


init : ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, Cmd.none )



-- MESSAGES


type Msg
    = WidgetMsg Widget.Msg



-- VIEW


view : AppModel -> Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ Html.map WidgetMsg (Widget.view model.widgetModel)
        ]



-- UPDATE


update : Msg -> AppModel -> ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
update message model =
    case message of
        WidgetMsg subMsg ->
            let
                ( updatedWidgetModel, widgetCmd ) =
                    Widget.update subMsg model.widgetModel
            in
                ( { model | widgetModel = updatedWidgetModel }, Cmd.map WidgetMsg widgetCmd )



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : AppModel -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none



-- APP


main : Program Never AppModel Msg
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

I think this is the same idea behind https://stackoverflow.com/a/44275318/61624 but it has more description.